# Vista x64, gadget development, OLEDB Error: "provider cannot be found"

Tags: javascript, windows-vista, oledb

I'm developing a Vista gadget. The gadget is working with local .mdb database, OLEDB used. The code is following:

```
var cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + getDbFilePath() + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
connection.ConnectionString = cs;
```

It works under Vista 32, but fails under x64 with message:

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

When I'm running the javascript file from command line, no errors occurs. 
**getDbFilePath()** return correct path, database exists etc.

How to fix it? Maybe, there a sense to use other database provider?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no native Jet image registered/available for x64 - it is only available in 32bit processes on x64.  The sidebar executable is being run as a native x64 image - hence it fails.

Your choices seem limited:

1. Give up on Jet, e.g. switch to one of SQL Compact Edition, SQL Express or similar
2. Wrap your Jet calls in a surrogate 32bit COM object.  Register the object as out-of-process in the 64bit registry. e.g.

   http://dnjonline.com/article.aspx?ID=jun07_access3264
3. No x64 support

Trying to force the sidebar to run in 32bit mode appears difficult/impossible let alone unreasonable.

Comment: I'm using a legacy database, so switching database is not an option. So I will try create w wrapper.
Thanks for help.